# which sdk is needed to compile java me code for samsung tocco?

Tags: eclipse, java-me

I've developed an Android app which has replaced two previous systems written in J2ME. My boss has the old source code and needs it compiling for Samsung tocco phones. Which sdk/jar file do i need in Eclipse to make the source code compile?

I've had a look on the samsung web site but can't seem to find anything. Also it's not clear which operating system the Tocco phones use.

thanks in advance Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try installing Samsung SDK 1.2.2 for the Java ME platform:

http://developer.samsung.com/java/tools-sdks/New-Samsung-Java-SDK-1-2-2-release-28th-October-2010

And then taking the steps on how to create a Hello world with it:

http://developer.samsung.com/java/tools-sdks/Developing-HelloWorld-MIDlet-using-Samsung-SDK